# premake5: Cannot get the "Hello World" example to generate a Visual Studio solution

Tags: premake

I am trying to generate a solution file for the premake5 out of the wiki example.
https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Your-First-Script

Calling premake5 vs2012 produces the following error -
Error: premake5.lua:2: attempt to call global 'workspace' (a nil value)

Does anyone know how to fix that? It looks like premake5 does not recognize the workspace() function. I followed the installation instructions and assume that I downloaded and unpacked the console utility correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running an older version of the code. The `workspace()` call was just introduced and will appear in the next alpha release, which should come out sometime next week. In the meantime, just use `solution()` instead; your code will still work when the new alpha arrives.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Now it works. I will then switch to building premake manually in order to sync it with the docs.